# Phonegap and window.device is undefined at onDeviceReady for iOS7

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ios7

I need some help on understanding why does this happen?

It's very strange, but `window.device` is undefined inside onDeviceReady event handler BUT at the same time it is initialized and accessible, and returns correct data trough its properties due to Angular data binding.

I mean that `window.device` is undefined, but `{{$window.device}}` is an object a bit later.

Bootstrapping of an app starts exactly from `onDeviceReady`.

phonegap.js v3.1.0 is present in `platforms/ios/www`
a device plugin is available (working angular controller and view prove this)
Everything is ok in a browser or intel xdk emulator.

It works (or does not work) this way in iOS Simulator and on a real device with iOS7. It seems that there is a gap between firing onDeviceReady and window.device availability. It should not be there.

Comment: So you've 'added' the 'device' plugin to your project via the command line, and referenced the plugin in your config.xml (eg. <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />)?

Comment: @MattyJ, I've added all required plugins. `device` finally is available, but not at the moment I expect, considering a name of the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set 1 second timeout after onDeviceReady fires

Comment: According to my experience, at least 5 secs time-out is required. But I wonder, why the event is raised if `device` is not really ready yet.
At the same time another plugin `StatusBar` appears ready in `onDeviceReady`. Actually, I needed to manage an app appearance on a startup. Thus, `StatusBar` plugin solves my problem, and I don't need the `device`, but it's interesting to find out the reasons.